# How to edit PDF file which is exported with jspdf.min.js?

Tags: pdf, charts, jspdf

Don't know if the question is well put, but here is my problem: I managed to export my chart to PDF format using `jspdf.min.js` through this piece of code:

```
          $("#generate").on("click", function (e) {
            html2canvas($("#placeholder").get(0), {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                    console.log('Report Image URL: ' + imgData);
                    var doc = new jsPDF('portrait');

                    doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10, 190, 95);
                    doc.text("TEST TEXT");//I tried to add a text in PDF file,but didn't work
                    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');                        
                }
            });
         });
```

Is there a way to add a title of my chart in the PDF file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/9x7aJ/3326/). Is a trick which might help you. Don't forget to update your options:

```
var options = {
            canvas: true,
            grid: {
                margin: {
                    top:50
                },
            }
    };
```